# Counting in HTML form with already known results from Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I need help.

I'm already pretty clueless, looking for a solution to my problem.

I have a form that I want to use as a calculation tool.
However, not only static tasks count. I thought I would solve it in the easiest way, and it was a setting in javascript, with already finished results, which would be returned to the user after clicking.

Example:

The customer selects 8 (10 maximum) service hours in advance in the form. In the next step, he chooses that he also wants a weekend (yes-no choice) emergency. And in the next step, for example, selects that 5 (5 maximum) computers.

And I would like

to have already predefined prices in JS which would be returned by the customer after selection and displayed.

The result that would be in JS:

8, no, 5 = $ 15 (customer would get a $ 15 result)
1, yes, 2 = $ 3 (customer would get a $ 3 result)

Those amounts are not static, so + - * / ... cannot be used

This solution would be super ...

Does anyone have an idea how to do this, please?

I am a newcomer to JS ..

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sounds like you first need to define a formula for calculating the prices / bulk discounts, or a lookup table if there is no consistent mathematical model that could be used. Then you can look up the right price in the table based on the item and quantity

Comment: Do you have an example somewhere, please?

Comment: example of what? I suggested 2 different things. Anyway the formula I don't know, it's just maths, but it depends on your rule. The table would just be a variable like an object or array (or some combination of the two). It's difficult to be more specific without knowing your full requirements.

Comment: Is it possible to use javascript to define answers, based on the user's selection in the form?

Suppose you choose in Form 8, yes, yes ...

and in JS it will be written that if the user selects exactly these options from the form, the result will show a defined result - for example $ 15.

Comment: yes you can definitely do that. It's just a simple conditional case.